# Use Graph to modify Exchange Online Send Connectors

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server, microsoft-graph-sdks

## Background

A client organisation is so huge that five years ago Office 365 could not handle the number of mailboxes required. As a result, things were divided up using DNS subdomains. To make this transparent, email addresses are transformed going in and out to embed (or extract) routing information in mailbox names.

Exchange Online can now handle millions of mailboxes so the jiggery-pokery is to be decommissioned. Big-bang would create a multi-week outage, so it has to be done piecemeal by division. This approach also provides damage containment for unforeseen problems and opportunities for refinement of the porting automation.

Part of the routing is done using Exchange Connector selection by Address Space. As subdomains are retired they must be removed from the Address Space of the connector. Details are here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/mail-flow/mail-routing/connector-selection?view=exchserver-2019

We already know how to do this using PowerShell, but it's slow and not well suited to other requirements. Web searches for "exchange connector microsoft graph" turn up only information on connectors for other things to talk to Graph.

## Questions

- Is it possible to modify the Address Space of an Exchange Connector using Microsoft Graph?
- If so, where is the documentation for this?
- If there's an SDK what is the name?

Comment: Someone has voted this down, naturally without a word of explanation. Why? It's a real question that received a definite usable answer. Do you disapprove of people looking for higher performance alternatives? Is this some kind of forbidden knowledge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Graph API supports your Exchange Online requirements on mail, calendar and contacts. As of now, Graph REST API doesn't support creation of any objects in Exchange Online tenant. that means, at present the support is limited to the content in the mailbox.

I suggest you to go with PowerShell where you can create custom scripts and modify the connector properties easily